# why cannot get outgoing response from application insights dependency telemetry?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

I use below code to get the outgoing request/response from telemetry initializer in my Asp.Net Core service:

```
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        if (telemetry is DependencyTelemetry)
        {
            var dependencyTelemetry = telemetry as DependencyTelemetry;

            if (dependencyTelemetry.TryGetOperationDetail("HttpRequest", out var request))
            {
                var httpRequest = request as HttpRequestMessage;
            }

            if (dependencyTelemetry.TryGetOperationDetail("HttpResponse", out var response))
            {
                var httpResponse = response as HttpResponseMessage;
            }
        }
    }
```

I can get request successfully with above code, but the response from TryGetOperationDetail is always null. Anything wrong in my code?